How are plagiarism cases, within the same institution, typically resolved, in the US?
Let's say X did some work at a research institution, and then he left. Then years later, another person Y at the same institution published this work, perhaps further augmented, but without saying it was X's work. And let's say this person Y was also receiving R01 grants from the NIH, where he made the same claims in progress reports, etc.
The institution owns the IP rights to the work due to the employee agreements. However, I feel like this is still plagiarism, even though this isn't IP theft? Further the money Y was receiving from the NIH is justified by this work.
I wonder how such cases are typically resolved? Monetary compensations? Non-disparagement agreements?
Have there been any such cases in the public record that I could look up?

sorry, but "The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as some person’s preferences, some institution’s policies, the exact contents of some work or the asker’s personal values. Answers to this question would be far too speculative, broad, or would primarily consist of: “It depends on X.” See this FAQ for details. Note that questions on the rules of institutions that operate at national or international level are permitted." and per your question title, this is institution specific.

@RichardErickson I'm not asking about policies, but known cases, and how they've been resolved.

You shouldn't make edits to your question that invalidate existing answers. The question you've edited to seems like it belongs on Law.SE instead; I've added a link to a question already there that would likely be a duplicate, though.

@BryanKrause Fair enough. I'll try another edit.

@BryanKrause On second thought I don't know how to edit it. I do know (after doing more research) that the question was very answerable -- there is a list of known cases, and also I found that non-disparagement agreements are forbidden.

Since these things are rarely made public, you're looking at some rare events, but I'm glad you found what you were looking for.

@BryanKrause "rarely made public" -- That's what I thought, when I first asked the Q.

@BryanKrause ... When there is plagiarism involving federal funding, there are reporting requirements.

Plagiarism is an academic ethics concept. For a legal perspective, you might be better of checking a Q&A on Law Stack Exchange. Procedures for accusations against a faculty member would likely involve some sort of (possibly ad hoc) committee reviewing the situation. Sanctions would be the ordinary ones against an employee: a note on their permanent record, an obstacle to promotion, termination of employment. More severe sanctions are only going to happen in severe cases. Unfortunately the university likely has some face to save so it may be difficult to have anything done. If specific publications, etc are involved then the committee may request retractions, or that could be an entirely separate process.
It's important not to confuse plagiarism with legal concepts of intellectual property; if you were to make a civil claim, it would not be based on "plagiarism" but based on some other legal reason. If you wanted to pursue a claim on those sorts of issues, you need a lawyer. You'd likely need to show that you were harmed, not just that someone else would benefit. Remember that ideas are only protected in very narrow circumstances through patents; after ideas are disclosed to others they're very unlikely to be patentable. Copyright gives some protection of specific works (like text) but not the ideas they contain. A grant is not typically given based on intellectual property ownership, especially not a grant from a federal source, it's given based on a proposed plan for future research.

Actually, plagiarism can sometimes be construed as fraud and fraud against the US government is a crime. The internet knows. So, it isn't so simple in the OP's context.

@Buffy Then it's fraud, not plagiarism. There is no crime of plagiarism. There are related illegal activities like copyright or patent infringement, but these are illegal because they violate copyright or a patent, not because they're plagiarism. That is, some activity can be "both", but the plagiarism part is the academic ethics part. If you violate a patent but give credit for where the ideas originated (therefore not plagiarism) it does absolutely nothing for any legal case based on the patent, the plagiarism component is irrelevant.

Hmmm. Do the search. Read the results.

I did the search and read the results. I have to agree with Bryan. Quoting from the document: "plagiarism is not a crime...Further, there is no direct tort...recognized in US law for plagiarism...While rare, it is possible for plagiarism to be charged under fraud statutes." The latter is very uncommon and is usually related to more serious things like grant fraud.

"Most of your question seems to confuse plagiarism with legal concepts of intellectual property." No. I specifically point out that they are different (and to my knowledge, there is no IP theft, due to the institution owning the IP, regardless)

@MWB I may have misread, then, I've changed that statement. If there's no IP theft I don't see what possible claim you would have here, you're basically saying so by saying there's no problem with the IP which is why I got the impression you had them confused.
